# JSON mime type for dynamically created content with PHP

Tags: php, json, dynamic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [correct HTTP header for json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267546/correct-http-header-for-json-file)

I have set the header of a php file using the following line:

```
header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

The server fails with the error message:

```
"Tue Oct 23 16:20:09 2012] [error] [client 111.111.111.111] malformed header from script. Bad header=Content-Type: xyz.php, referer:...."
```

I followed some advice on the web to add this to an .htaccess file

```
AddType application/json .json
```

Neither have worked. I'd be grateful for any further assistance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Answer (score 1):

notice where the quotes are in the `header()`

`header('Content-type: application/json');`